# Reference main selection table inside joined selection table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables with similar data. Wanting to find closest matches for comparison. Here's what I was trying to do:

```
select a.field1 as a1, b.field1 as b1, a.field2 as a2, b.field2 as b2
from foo a
left join (
   select top 1 tmp.field1, tmp.field2
   from foo2 tmp
   -- The closest match will match the most fields. Add up these.
   order by case when tmp.field1 = a.field1 then 1 else 0 end
          + case when tmp.field2 = a.field2 then 1 else 0 end
          desc) b on 1 = 1
```

I can't reference the main selection table in the join though.

Perhaps I'm going about it all wrong. The actual goal is that I was given a spreadsheet of data and told to update a database. The spreadsheet has no PK and is missing many fields that the database has. Also, the database has foreign keys and child data all over. So I don't want to delete/insert. Instead I want to compare values and update wherever possible.  So I created two temporary tables and pulled the database records into one and the spreadsheet records into another. Now I'm wanting to work with those two tables to update records, and finally delete/insert where no update is available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked up the MERGE statement? It does what you want, although the syntax is a bit tricky.

Article here with half decent examples:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I know of the merge statement, yes. But I want to view the data side by side before implementing any changes. Data that might look similar maybe shouldn't be matched.